# How to retrieve data with multiple join in my sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, inner-join

I have following table in my SQL database

user_

```
userId | userName
```

organization_

```
org_id | parent_org_id_ | name
```

role_

```
roleId | roleName
```

user_roles

```
userId | roleId
```

users_organization

```
userId |  organizationId
```

...Now what i want is from org_Id= ? and role_name = ? I want to retrieve the name of the user from user_ table related to that organization with the specific role name.so can anyone please tell me.. how to do it?

Comment: You have to use select and [inner joins](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try ::

```
Select *
from
user_ u
INNER JOIN user_roles ur on (u.userId = ur.userId)
INNER JOIN role_ r on (ur.roleId = r.roleId)

INNER JOIN users_organization uo (u.userId = uo.userId)
INNER JOIN organization_ o on (uo.organizationId= o.orgId)
where uo.org_id =? and  r.role_name=?
```

Comment: thanx for your answer but i want to select user_name based on particular org_id and role_name

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly (your question lacks the table relationships):

```
SELECT U.userId
    , U.userName
    FROM user_ U
    INNER JOIN users_organization UO ON UO.userId = U.userId
    INNER JOIN user_roles UR ON UR.userId = U.userId
    WHERE UO.organizationId = organizationId
        AND UR.roleName = roleName;
```

The parameters are `organizationId` and `roleName`.

Answer (score 1):

Try it out below suggestion.

```
SELECT u.userName
FROM user_ u
   , role_ r
   , users_organization uo
   , user_roles ur
WHERE r.roleName = ?
  AND uo.organizationId = ?
  AND ur.userId = u.userId 
  AND ur.roleId = r.roleId 
  AND u.userId = uo.userId
```